# How can I make a menu item change its label when I press and hold the option key?

Tags: applescript, appkit, foundation

I want to be able to make a menu item a bit more powerful by having an alternate behavior when the option key is held and clicked. What I need is similar to when you press the option button in Finder, where you get the option "Copy 'seletedfile' as Pathname". How is this accomplished in AppleScript/Objective-C?

Here's my template code for creating regular menu items:

```
set menuItems to {"POC1", "POC2"}
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in menuItems
    set this_item to item i of menuItems
    if i is equal to selectedIndex then set this_item to this_item & " " & (emoji's CHECK)
    set thisMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:this_item action:("someAction" & (i as text) & ":") keyEquivalent:"")
    (newMenu's addItem:thisMenuItem)
    (thisMenuItem's setTarget:me) -- required for enabling the menu item
end repeat
```

Comment: See [How do I use isAlternative with an NSMenuItem with a customView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986112/how-do-i-use-isalternative-with-an-nsmenuitem-with-a-customview)

Comment: Thank you @Willeke, I am able to fulfill my requirement based on the link you shared.